# Set meta field to publish date + 2 weeks

Tags: php, hooks, actions, date, publish

I have a meta field called `postexpiry`, and I want to set the value to the publish date, + 2 weeks.
So if today were October 3rd, I want the field to be set to October 17th.

I was thinking about creating a hook to the `publish_post` filter, but I am not sure how to add 2 weeks on to `get_the_date()`.

I know with php I can do something like this `$dateInTwoWeeks = strtotime('+2 weeks');` but I'm not sure how to use that with `get_the_date()`

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I tried the following code, but it didn't do anything:

```
function dp_expiry() {

$dp_new_expiry_date = strtotime( '+2 weeks', strtotime( $post->post_date ) );
update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'postexpiry', $dp_new_expiry_date );
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'dp_expiry' );
```

**Also**, my theme requires that the date be in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

**UPDATE 2**

This code outputs "1209600" to the field. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
add_action('publish_post', 'dp_expiry');
function dp_expiry( $data ) {

$dp_new_expiry_date = strtotime( '+2 weeks', strtotime( $post->post_date ) );

update_post_meta( $data['post_id'], 'postexpiry', $dp_new_expiry_date );
}
```

Comment: With `publish_post`, you can use `$post->post_date` instead of `get_the_date()`. So try with `strtotime( '+2 weeks', strtotime( $post->post_date ) )`. I.e. Get the post publish date timestamp, and use it with your existing `strtotime()` call.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I updated my original post with code that I tried, but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'dp_expiry');
function dp_expiry( $data ) {
    /*adds 2 weeks onto the current date in unix epoch format*/
$dp_new_expiry_date = (strtotime( current_time( 'mysql' ) ) + 1209600);
        /*converts unix timstamp back to yyyy-mm-dd format like you required*/
    $dp_new_expiry_date_conv = date("Y-m-d", $dp_new_expiry_date);
update_post_meta( $data['post_id'], 'postexpiry', $dp_new_expiry_date_conv );
}
```

Comment: This is not canonical, but some sort of individual hack, and should be marked as such, in my opinion: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/new_status_post-post_type/. Otherwise, people who read this will expect their `publish_post` hook to be passed a `$data` array type, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_ID()` is a loop function and might not work here. You should use the parameters of your callback instead:

```
function dp_expiry( $ID, $post ) {

    $dp_new_expiry_date = strtotime( '+2 weeks', strtotime( $post->post_date ) );

    update_post_meta( $ID, 'postexpiry', $dp_new_expiry_date );
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'dp_expiry', 10, 2 );
```

`publish_post` only works for posts, not pages. You can use `publish_{post_type}` for a custom post type.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it, but still nothing. I just noticed my them requires that the date be in yyyy-mm-dd format. Could that be the cause of the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by `nothing`? It works on a clean WP install, and it only works if the post status *changes* to 'publish'.

Comment: I wasn't getting anything in the meta field with that code. When I echoed the field, it just said the word "array". I changed around the code a little (posted above), and now it saves "1209600" to the field. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are passing to your `dp_expiry` function. Myself, I am using Wordpress and the `publish_post` hook: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post. Have a nice day.